# Load dynamic content in a wordpress website

Tags: custom-content

is there a way to load a page content ( or an element ) from a page into another one on a same Wordpress website? For example, if I had a page with some links would it be possible to make a specific element ( such as a div ), that comes from an another page, appear in a specific part of the page? If it was possible, can anyone help me reaching out the best way to do it  ( which language use and in which way use it ) ? I hope someone could help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna call content of one page to another page then for that you need to make [custom template](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/).

For example if you have 2 pages (page a and page b) then make template for `page a`. And now you want to add content of `page b` into `page a`, this can be done with following code

```
$include = get_pages('include=10'); //Assigning ID of page
$content = apply_filters('the_content',$include[0]->post_content);
echo $content;
```

In the above code code I have assign ID 10 to get_pages() function, just for demo purpose. Replace 10 with your actual page ID whose content you want to show in `page a`.

Just Paste the above code in custom template (made for page a) on location of your choice and `page b` content will get appear on that location.

Comment: Useful reply, but I wanted to make a page where the user could choose a specific div of another page dynamically through a list of some links...so each link would generate a dynamic content without page refresh. Practically, this problem could be solved with AJAX and Javascript, but I could not do it with Wordpress.

Comment: @Michele You haven't mentioned this in your question earlier, that's why I came up with this solution. If you want to do it without page load then sorry to say but I can't help you in that because I don't have knowledge of AJAX.